# SQL using WHERE clause and ALIASING data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

The Prompt:

Construct the SQL statement to find all of the messages that Michael Phelps sent.

Note: You must use the WHERE clause to set the conditions for this query.

Display the following columns:

- Sender's first name
- Sender's last name
- Receiver's first name
- Receiver's last name
- Message ID
- Message
- Message Timestamp

The tables;

```
SELECT * FROM contact_list;
+---------------+-----------+------------+----------+
| connection_id | person_id | contact_id | favorite |
+---------------+-----------+------------+----------+
|             1 |         1 |          2 | n        |
|             2 |         1 |          3 | n        |
|             3 |         1 |          4 | n        |
|             4 |         1 |          5 | n        |
|             5 |         1 |          6 | n        |
|             6 |         2 |          1 | y        |
|             7 |         2 |          3 | n        |
|             8 |         2 |          4 | n        |
|             9 |         3 |          1 | y        |
|            10 |         3 |          4 | n        |
|            11 |         4 |          5 | n        |
|            12 |         4 |          6 | n        |
|            13 |         5 |          1 | y        |
|            14 |         5 |          6 | n        |
|            15 |         7 |          1 | y        |
|            16 |         7 |          2 | n        |
|            17 |         7 |          4 | n        |
+---------------+-----------+------------+----------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM person;
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
| person_id | first_name | last_name | person_age |
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
|         1 | Michael    | Phelps    |            |
|         2 | Katie      | Ledecky   |            |
|         3 | Usain      | Bolt      |            |
|         4 | Allyson    | Felix     |            |
|         5 | Kevin      | Durant    |            |
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM message;
+------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| message_id | sender_id | receiver_id | message                                    | send_datetime       |
+------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|          1 |         1 |           2 | Congrats on winning the 800m Freestyle!    | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 |
|          2 |         2 |           1 | Congrats on winning 23 gold medals!        | 2016-12-25 09:01:00 |
|          3 |         3 |           1 | You're the greatest swimmer ever           | 2016-12-25 09:02:00 |
|          4 |         1 |           3 | Thanks!  You're the greatest sprinter ever | 2016-12-25 09:04:00 |
|          5 |         1 |           4 | Good luck on your race                     | 2016-12-25 09:05:00 |
+------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've tried just about everything I can think of to solve this problem, and I have only gotten close using the following statement:

```
SELECT sender_id, receiver_id, message_id, message, send_datetime 
FROM messaging.message 
WHERE sender_id = 1;

+-----------+-------------+------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| sender_id | receiver_id | message_id | message                                    | send_datetime       |
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|         1 |           2 |          1 | Congrats on winning the 800m Freestyle!    | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 |
|         1 |           3 |          4 | Thanks!  You're the greatest sprinter ever | 2016-12-25 09:04:00 |
|         1 |           4 |          5 | Good luck on your race                     | 2016-12-25 09:05:00 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

All of the results being displayed are correct, besides the missing name columns. However, because I am unable to properly alias each column and produce the same results, I am unsure if this is even the correct approach. Please help

Comment: so the results you have mentioned above is correct?

Comment: @Standin.Wolf Yes, the command at the end actually provides the majority of the necessary fields except for the first name/last name of the sender and the first name/last name of the receiver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    s.first_name, 
    s.last_name, 
    r.first_name, 
    r.last_name, 
    m.message_id, 
    m.message, 
    m.send_datetime
FROM message m 
INNER JOIN person s 
    ON s.person_id=m.sender_id 
INNER JOIN person r 
    ON r.person_id=m.receiver_id 
WHERE
    s.first_name = 'Michael'
    AND s.last_name='Phelps';
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this actually actually works both initially and after properly aliasing each component.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you're after something like this?

```sql
SELECT  CONCAT(first_name , ' ' ,last_name ) AS sender,
        CONCAT(first_name , ' ' ,last_name ) AS receiver,
        message_id,
        message,
        send_datetime

FROM    person  p
        JOIN message m ON m.sender_id = p.person_id OR m.receiver_id = p.person_id

WHERE   sender_id = 1
```